# how to redirect to app controller to plugin controller file

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('plugin'=>'Usermgmt','controller'=>'user','action' => 'search')); ?>
                        <?php echo $this->Form->input("search" ,array('label' => false ))?>

                        <?php echo $this->Form->Submit(__('Search'));?>
```

This the code am using for search user name am using this code in **view\pages\home.ctp**
and the search function in plugin is Usermgmt .. but now am getting error using above code

when am click on search it goes to url like `Exp/users/search` but it should be `Exp/usermgmt/users/search`

Comment: @AD7six cakephp-2.4.5 and actually when am click on search it goes to url like `Exp/users/search` but it should be `Exp/usermgmt/users/search`

Answer (score 1):

### The options array is malformed

The second parameter for `Form::create` is [$options](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::create) - [the api](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-FormHelper.html#_create) (and [the source](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.7/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L301-L326), on which the api is based) lists the available options:

- type
- action
- url
- default
- onsubmit
- inputDefaults
- encoding

As such, with the following call:

```
echo $this->Form->create(
    'User', 
    array(
        'plugin'=>'Usermgmt', # <-
        'controller'=>'user', # <-
        'action' => 'search' 
    )
);
```

Everything marked with an arrow will be ignored.

### Use the url key

To change the form action, use the `url` key:

```
echo $this->Form->create(
    'User', 
    array(
        'url' => array(
            'plugin'=>'usermgmt',
            'controller'=>'users',
            'action' => 'search'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: done it show error in url `http://localhost/Projects/Exp/Usermgmt/user/search` **Error: UsermgmtController could not be found**

Comment: Is it the right url? You need to think about what you are doing/asking :).